# Grouping with reduce in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Is it possible to group them by 'country' using array.reduce method?
Any advice appreciated.

```
const table = { 
  0: {
    firstName: 'Mark',
    lastName: 'Spencer',
    adress: {
      Country: 'England',
      Town:    'London',
      Street: 'Old street',
      Postcode: 'W2 1RB'
    }
  },
  1: {
    firstName: 'Franz',
    lastName: 'Muller',
    adress: {
      Country: 'Germany',
      Town: 'Berlin'
      Street: 'Wilhelmstrasse',
      Postcode: '10115 - 14199'
    }
  },
  2: {
    firstName: 'William',
    lastName: 'Davies',
    adress: {
      Country: 'England',
      Town:    'Liverpool'
      Street: 'New Street',
      Postcode: 'l1 0au'
    }
```

How can I correctly sort them using this method only?

Comment: Please be more specific. Do you want to group it or sort it? What would be the desired output? Why "this method only"? `Array.prototype.reduce` cannot be applied on objects.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your question. The desired output is to group them by countries using array.reduce, it's just for the sake of practicing array.reduce on more coplex arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your object with keys like indices with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to an array and then reduce it.

```js
var data = { 0: { firstName: 'Mark', lastName: 'Spencer', address: { Country: 'England', Town: 'London', Street: 'Old street', Postcode: 'W2 1RB' } }, 1: { firstName: 'Franz', lastName: 'Muller', address: { Country: 'Germany', Town: 'Berlin', Street: 'Wilhelmstrasse', Postcode: '10115 - 14199' } }, 2: { firstName: 'William', lastName: 'Davies', address: { Country: 'England', Town: 'Liverpool', Street: 'New Street', Postcode: 'l1 0au' } } },
    grouped = Object
        .assign([], data)
        .reduce((r, o) => {
            var key = o.address.Country;
            (r[key] = r[key] || []).push(o);
            return r;
        }, Object.create(null));
    
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.values` to get the values of your object as an array. The keys to your table seem to have no meening; they are just indexes. It's the values you want to group: using `Object.values` makes this clear.

Once you have an array, you can use `Array.prototype.reduce`. I wrapped `groupBy` in a reusable function that uses `reduce` internally.

```js
const table = { 0: { firstName: 'Mark', lastName: 'Spencer', address: { Country: 'England', Town: 'London', Street: 'Old street', Postcode: 'W2 1RB' } }, 1: { firstName: 'Franz', lastName: 'Muller', address: { Country: 'Germany', Town: 'Berlin', Street: 'Wilhelmstrasse', Postcode: '10115 - 14199' } }, 2: { firstName: 'William', lastName: 'Davies', address: { Country: 'England', Town: 'Liverpool', Street: 'New Street', Postcode: 'l1 0au' } } };

const groupBy = (getId, array) => 
  array.reduce(
    (groups, x) => {
      const k = getId(x);
      if (!groups[k]) groups[k] = [];
      groups[k].push(x);
      return groups;
    },
    {}
  );
  
  
console.log(
  groupBy(
    person => person.address.Country,
    Object.values(table)
  )
)
```